# Puppeteer Login Selector: no node found?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I want to click on a login button on a website when I'm trying to login however its giving me an error of no node found for a selector

input=[name="Log In"]

and this is how the website login looks liike

```
<input type="submit" value="Log In" class="buttonss" style="font-size:19px">
```

How can i select this input in puppeteer?

this is what I have

```
await Promise.all([
page.click('input[name="Log In"]'),
page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" }),
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "name" prop on that input. Try:

`'input[value="Log In"]'`